# haskell-mode prints "*Main>" on same line after using putChar?

Tags: haskell, emacs, haskell-mode

Code:

```
main = do
  putChar 't'
  putChar 'e'
  putChar 'h'
```

While I run above-mentioned code, I am getting

```
*Main> main
teh*Main>
```

But I am expecting

```
*Main> main
teh
*Main>
```

My question: Why **teh*Main** comes instead of **teh** and then ***Main** in another line?

I am using emacs23 with haskell-mode.

Comment: "Because there is no newline" :P~ (Now who's responsible for it .. is the question.)

Comment: @pst: So, I have to just accept it as it is or ?

Comment: Well, you could always edit the .el, or there might be a setting .. I don't use haskell (or related modes), though :-) Other approaches might be to just put a newline char (\n should suffice) or force it through putStrLn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`putChar c` writes just that one character to the console. That's what it's intended for. So unless you print a newline to the console afterward, whether with `putChar`, `putStr` or whatever other methods, the following output goes to the same line. The behaviour is the same as with C, or if you `cat` a file without trailing newline. It's ubiquitous. The only feasible alternative (it's unfeasible to check each output whether it ended with a newline) is to output a newline before the ghci or shell prompt unconditionally, which would lead to many annoying blank lines.

Answer (score 2):

If it *really* bothers you, you could always define

```
putCharLn :: Char -> IO ()
putCharLn c = do putChar c
                 putChar '\n'
```

Define `main` like:

```
main = do putChar 't'
          putChar 'e'
          putCharLn 'h'
```

And now:

```
*Main> main
teh
*Main>
```